How can I determine if this metal flange is wide enough to support a load without permanently deforming?
I'm designing a sheet metal panel for an enclosure, which will be built of 1.6mm thick 5052 H32 Aluminum.
The panel looks like this:

The panel will fit inside a four-sided frame. The top is fitted into place with registration pins from above (into the oval slots), and is not supported from above. All the support comes from below. A cross member will have three threaded holes that mate with the three screw holes shown at the bottom. The two "feet" will also sit on the cross-member:

Because of the way I need to "scoop" the panel in from below so that the oval slots maneuver under the pins and up into them, I can't make the feet especially wide, to avoid contact with the support member underneath. Because of the need for relief around other folds in the area, I also can't make the bend line the full 10mm width of the foot; it's only 5.2mm wide.
My question is: will the weight of the panel cause it to deform the bend at the foot?
The panel's overall mass is 581g (1.28 lbs). Worst case, I think all that mass is supported at the very end of one foot, which is 30mm away from the bend line.
I vaguely understand that this has to do with the elastic modulus of the material, but don't know how to model this. A bending calculator I used says the maximum bending stress (σ_max) = 13.0 ksi. I don't know how to take it from there to determine whether that exceeds the material property to determine whether it causes a plastic deformation. (Or if there's anything else I need to take into account.)

I'm sure there's an engineering solution but my advice is take a simpler approach & ask a welder.  Those guys know what 1.6 mm AL will hold (that seems really thin to me, but I'm not fab guy.)

Sounds like I need to go make friends with a welder ;)
I don't have a great frame of reference for metal thickness. Hammond's (larger) aluminum equipment enclosures are 2.03mm (80 thou) aluminum, which is a bit thicker. Overall I think the part thickness is OK because the flanges (1.25" top, 3/4" sides) should add the rigidity needed by the main rectangle. I'd rather not double the weight (or cost) of the panel just to thicken up the feet...

Please add the material that frame is made of.You have a cantilever resting on a sprung foundation in effect. If the materials is aluminium then the brunt of the load will be taken by the root of the cantilever, if the foundation is very soft, then it will be more equally distributed. Assuming it is all at the tip is the worst case scenario but of course might happen during installation. Also as it deforms it will tend to even the load out.

Thanks Greg. The frame will be hardwood. The static position is probably less my concern than me doing something clumsy with it during installation.

So stresses in a cantilever made of 1.6mm thick 5052 H32 aluminum with a tip load. Here's the material properties

so sigma_yield=160 N/mm^2. L=30mm b=5.2mm d=1.6mm
I=1/12 * b * d^3=1.77 mm^4
The only structural formula I bother to remember is
M/I=sigma/y
M=F * L
y=d/2
Fmax=I * sigma/L/d * 2=12 N
While 12 N is substantially more than half the weight of your panel it is still a pretty low value. However the failure mode is benign, as the tip is forced upwards more of the load will be applied to the root of the beam, and it will be supported there. In service the three screws take all the loads in shear/friction. You've also got a rebate in the wooden frame, this will help with both alignment and jigging during assembly.
